# Jsonxx - iterate through Json

Tags: c++, json

I'm using [Jsonxx library](https://github.com/hjiang/jsonxx)
I need to iterate through some json values, for example:

```
    {
        "unknowName1" : { "foo" : bar }
        "unknowName2" : { "foo" : bar }
    }
```

It's obvious that I need some sort of iterator, but I can't do it and jsonxx isn't very popular or rich in documentation. Unfortunately I can't use other json library. 
I tried this:

```
    Object o;
    o.parse(json);
    std::map<std::string, Value*> * jsonMap = o.kv_map;
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>::iterator it_type;
    for (it_type iterator = jsonMap->begin(); iterator != jsonMap->end(); iterator++) 
    {
    doing stuff here
    }
```

But jsonxx doesn't provide neither conversion to iterator nor override for "!=" operator.

Comment: Strange case of an answerable question about a poorly documented not so popular json parser library.

Comment: Agree, this API is terrible. There are better choices for JSON C++. Frankly, I am impressed with this new little code generator *jsoncpp* and its JSON C/C++ API [JSON/JSONPath](http://www.genivia.com/doc/xml-rpc-json/html/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But jsonxx doesn't provide neither conversion to iterator nor override for "!=" operator.

That's a misconception. There's no need that `jsonxx` needs to *override* anything. Their implementation works well just with the standard c++ containers implementations.

As from their (admittedly poorly documented) interface it looks like you need a `const_iterator` actually

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Value*>>::const_iterator it_type;
                                                                 // ^^^^^^^^
```

as the `kv_map()` function returns a `const std::map<std::string, Value*>&`

> Signature as seen in the header:
>
> ```
> const std::map<std::string, Value*>& kv_map() const;
> ```

also you need to change

```
std::map<std::string, Value*> * jsonMap = o.kv_map;
```

to

```
const std::map<std::string, Value*>& jsonMap = o.kv_map();
                                // ^                   ^^ it's a function, so call it
                                // | there's no pointer returned but a const reference
```

to get the syntax right.

Finally the loop should look like this then:

```
for (it_type iterator = jsonMap.begin(); iterator != jsonMap.end(); ++iterator) {
     // doing stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 and up you can iterate very easily using the auto initialization, leading to something like this:

```
for(auto kv : o.kv_map)
{
    jsonxx::Object obj = kv.second->get<jsonxx::Object>();
    // do stuff here
    std::cout << obj.json() << std::endl;
}
```